# Seaborn plot a distribution plot where the color is the average value of a 3rd dimension

Tags: python, seaborn

My data `data` is a 3-dimensional matrix, of the shape `X, Y, Z`.
I want to plot something that is visually like a 2d distribution plot, e.g:

[image]

Where the location of each square is given by `X` and `Y` but the color (hue and intensity) is given by the average value of `Z` of the points within the square regardless of the density.

How can I achieve that with seaborn?

Using a scatter plot with hue does not serve me as many points overlay and I want to see the average of all the points within an area

Comment: See this part of the seaborn tutorial: https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html#visualizing-bivariate-distributions

Comment: That does not help me, the intensity of the colors are given by the density of how many points are in the squares, which is not what I want. I want the intensity and color to be a function of the average value of `Z` regardless of how many points are in that area

Comment: Could you post some sample data?

Comment: You can just use `data = np.random.uniform(size=(10000, 3))` then use `data[:, :2]` for the `X`-`Y` placement and use `data[:, 2]` for the color. The idea is to ignore the number of points of each square and just use the value of `Z`/`data[:, 2]` to dictate the color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sns.heatmap()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html), but it is a bit tricky to get the data in the right shape. Here is one way to do it, using `df.round()` to bin the points into 11x11 tiles.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

n = 10_000  # number of points

data = np.random.uniform(size=(n, 3))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])

df[['X', 'Y']] = df[['X', 'Y']].round(1)
tiles = df.groupby(['X', 'Y']).mean()

tile_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(11, 11))
for x, y, z in tiles.reset_index().values:
    tile_matrix[int(10 * x), int(10 * y)] = z

sns.heatmap(tile_matrix, cmap='Blues');
```

[image: heatmap example]